# RegEx expression to find only exact match with Capitalization variants

Tags: regex

I want to filter down landing pages in Analytics to just see traffic from “/ph” and “/pH” only, and not include other pages that have like /ph-electrode-maintenance-calibration-guide. (ph|pH) didn't work, Any help would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHtGz.png)

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Specify *Start of String `^` and End of String `$` Anchors*:

`^\/p[hH]$`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\/p(h|H)(\/?$|\/))` it will match all your paths, eg:

*path/pH*

*path/ph*

*path/pH/anything*

*path/ph/anything*

but not:

*path/ph-electrode-maintenance-calibration-guide*

Add a `^` to the beginning if your path always begins with */ph*:

`^(\/p(h|H)(\/?$|\/))`

Try [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3f4vl) to test it out